# DynamicsGP eConnect: cannot connect to endpoint

Tags: python, .net, wcf, ironpython, microsoft-dynamics

I'm using IronPython to use eConnect's .NET API for integration of expense reports with GP.

When

```
result = conn.CreateTransactionEntity(connection_string, xml)
```

is executed, I get this error:

```
StandardError: Cannot connect to endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/Microsoft/Dynamics/GP/eConnect/EntityOperations'
```

Does anyone know what would cause this sort of issue? This same code has worked on other machines without error but for some reason it won't agree with the eConnect configuration on this particular one.

Answer (score 1):

You must turn off the RequireProxyService property, so your code is:

```
conn.RequireProxyService = false;
result = conn.CreateTransactionEntity(connection_string, xml)
```